# Making Yii implicitly use classes

Tags: php, yii

I have a 3rd party library that I import this way:

```
Yii::setPathOfAlias('Payum', dirname(__FILE__).'/../extensions/PayumYiiExtension/vendor');
Yii::import('Payum.autoload', true); // <--- note that this is Composer's autoload class
```

Now, everything is working as expected if I write some explicit `use` lines:

```
use Buzz\Client\Curl;
use Payum\Core\Extension\StorageExtension;
use Payum\Core\Storage\FilesystemStorage;
use ...
```

But I'm wondering if there is any way to make Yii auto-load/use those classes when they are used, instead of having to write all those `use` lines myself.

Comment: You can keep using the full classname everywhere, like `Payum\core\Storage\FilesystemStorage`, but addig a `use` statement is the recommended (and more readable) way.

Comment: @Maerlyn Yes, I'm aware of that, but my question is how(if possible) can I make Yii write some implicit `use` statements when I use some of those classes.

Comment: There's no such thing as "implicit use statement".